# Make ajax call without using GWT widgets

Tags: gwt

I've seen a lot of GWT examples and all of them are using GWT widgets to make an ajax call. Is there any way to make the ajax call from an HTML page without using GWT widgets? I already checked [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997417/simple-ajax-with-gwt-i-dont-need-widgets), but I can't get anything useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google the GWT stock watcher example which includes making a "hand rolled" request to a PHP script on the server side.

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/JSON#http